# Annotations auto-keying even though auto keying is off

Tags: annotation

I'm trying to make annotations that span several keyframes.
The autokeyframing button is off.
But when I draw annotations, a keyframe is automatically created, so I can't draw notes that show on all frames of my animations.
Help?

[image: auto keying annotations]

Answer (score 2):

By default, if you move to another frame, the new annotation will create a new keyframe and will replace the former annotation. To change that, in the *N panel > View > Annotation*, click on the *Lock Frame* button and the annotation will stay along the timeline even if you draw over it. Unlock when you want to come back to the previous setting.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out